# Multicopter odd or even

Tags: quadcopter

I would like to ask which is better to design the multicopter with odd or even number of propellers? and why?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, it is a trade off between control complexity vs. power requirements. You should probably go with an even number, 4 or greater. Nice explanation of all the technicalities:

[Why do quadcopters have four propellers?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/543/why-do-quadcopters-have-four-propellers-besides-the-name/544#544)
[How to choose the right propeller/motor combination for a quadcopter?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/25/how-to-choose-the-right-propeller-motor-combination-for-a-quadcopter)